# Is a lamdba:function() inside the same function considered recursive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, recursion, lambda

I was watching this tutorial of how to make an image viewer:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg4c92pNFeo&t=1186s

Basically my question is if this part of code is considered recursive or not and why:

```
def forward(image_number):
    global my_label
    global button_forward
    global button_back

    my_label.grid_forget()
    my_label = tk.Label(image=image_list[image_number-1])
    button_forward = tk.Button(root, text=">>", command=lambda:forward(image_number+1))    #is this recursive?
    button_back = tk.Button(root, text="<<", command=lambda:back(image_number-1))
```

Comment: Off topic but it is really bad practice to create a new button every click stacked on top of each other. Should simply do `button.config(command=...)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `forward` does not call itself, directly or otherwise. It simply creates a button that *can* call `forward` at some point in the future. (I'm assuming that `forward` exits without actually triggering the button's callback function. If it *did*, I'd consider that somewhat of a gray area.)

Comment: If it did trigger the callback, then it would be [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion#Basic_examples)

Comment: It's a weird kind, depending on what actually calls the callback.

Comment: _doesn't not_? is that a typo?

Comment: It seems like it exhibits potentially *recursive behavior* but indeed it's non-recursive if the user never triggers the callback.  Also, to meet the formal definition in mathematics (found on Wikipedia) it would need to return a single or multiple terminal scenarios which don't use recursion.